# Can you read line by line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, filereader, file-read

Is there any way to read a file line by line in javascript, specifically this [file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt) which is a dictionary. I was trying to build a replica of a java anagram solver I made a few months ago, but hit this problem of not being able to read a file line by line. I could download the file and store it locally if that would make any difference to being able to read it.

Comment: You can load any data from your own domain with AJAX. You'd use an XML HTTP Request.

Comment: Oh and if it's not your domain, then no, you can't do it (unless your browser is buggy). This would break the cross-origin request rules.

Comment: Since Javascript in the browser doesn't have access to a file system and the only other option is to go over the network, would you really want to go back and forth to the server in individual requests to read the file little by little? Maybe this simply isn't the right environment to solve this problem.

Comment: I believe he is asking about the HTML5 [FileReader API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader).

Comment: Thanks, for the comments. I have decided that maybe javascript is not correct for what I am try to achieve. I had not investigated HTML5 FileReader API so thanks for the mention, it may just be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use YQL:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fcollections%2Finterfaces%2Fexamples%2Fdictionary.txt%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc
```

## [Here's what the fiddle looks like:](http://jsfiddle.net/5EBKQ/)

```
window.callback = function(a) { window.file = a.query.results.body.p; go(); };

$.getScript('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fcollections%2Finterfaces%2Fexamples%2Fdictionary.txt%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=callback');

window.go = function() {
    var terms = file.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        console.log(terms[i])
};
```

The fiddle only does the first 100 but you get the idea (I hope).

Comment: This looks good, never used YQL before so I'll give this a try. Thanks for the code example :)

Answer (score 1):

In most circumstances, you could just read the file into memory and then parse it into lines.  If you read the whole thing into memory with an ajax call, you could just use `data.split("\n")` to convert it to an array of lines.

Comment: If I did this on a file with 100k+ lines, would it still be ok?

Comment: If each line was 100 bytes, that would be 10MB of RAM to hold the file.  On a desktop computer, that's fine - some images are that large.  On a phone, it's probably not a good idea, though perhaps still OK.

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate Ajax Request for such Operation. Reading a file line by line although is not recommended via Ajax, as you will end up create loads of server requests in the process;as JavaScript is all about Client side and limited access also. Ajax request to server is recent years add-on to it.

Definitely you are searching some information using some keywords; so it would be wise if you add the search logic on server functions; call the specific function via Ajax and return back result-set to the browser. That function could be a file that generates result or, a web service. You choose your flavor.

Alternate option would be to re-code the file information to JSON ([about JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html)) at start and let it roll to client js script. I would not recommend XML for this as its gonna eatup loads of browser memory in the processing terms. Been there! :(. Since JavaScript has native support to JSON, it will go smooth. Warning this exposes data to local.

Comment: I think that javascript is not the correct choice for the particular application I'm building. I don't have any experience with JSON but will look into it soon maybe if I can find some spare time(which rarely happens for me). Thanks for you comments.