# Can I use HTML5/Javascript to load specific number of lines instead of bytes of a local file?

Tags: javascript, html, io

I currently have some code in place to allow a user to select a local file, read in that file as text, and then output that text into a textarea. However, I would like to only read in the first N number of lines, since the files will likely be >10GB.

I know that it is possible to read in blob of files as ranges of bytes, but I was wondering if I can read lines of text files the same way. Here is my current code:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /><br>

<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        if (!files.length) {
          alert('Please select a file!');
          return;
        }

        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                document.getElementById('myInput').textContent = evt.target.result;
            }  
        };
        reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    }


document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

...and I have seen things like this being used:

```
var blob = file.slice(startingByte, endindByte);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

...but want lines instead of byte ranges. Thanks!

Comment: you have to just grab chunks and find your own lines. just keep track of how amny you've seen, you don't need to know how many there are...

Comment: I see what you mean. So, just grab a small chunk of data, count how many lines I have so far, and if it isn't enough, grab another chunk? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using YQL like in this previous answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970541/can-you-read-line-by-line-in-javascript

Comment: that's exactly what i mean. i had this exact code somewhere,  but i can't find it...